# How to put LazyColumn under whole content in android app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I just started learning `Jetpack compose`. I have an application in which I get a list of locations from the `RickAndMortyApi`, I have them loaded page by page, for this I use a LazyColumn and `collectAsLazyPagingItems()`.
And I ran into a problem that the `LazyColumn` overlaps all content (if I create it from inside the `main column`) or scrolls regardless of the content on the page (if I create it from the outside of the main column)

This is how I create a location list:

```
@Composable
    fun CreateList(locationItems: Flow<PagingData<LocationsItemsList>>) {

        val lazyLocationItems: LazyPagingItems<LocationsItemsList> =
            locationItems.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

        LazyColumn {
            items(lazyLocationItems) {
                it?.let { CreateLocationItem(location = it) }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Composable
    fun CreateLocationItem(location: LocationsItemsList) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(all = 12.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)),
                color = Color(61, 61, 68)
            ) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(6.dp)
                        .zIndex(5f)
                ) {

                    Text(
                        text = location.type,
                        color = Color.White,
                        maxLines = 1,
                        fontSize = 12.sp,

                        )
                    Text(
                        text = location.name,
                        color = Color.White,
                        maxLines = 1,
                        fontSize = 12.sp,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = location.dimension,
                        color = Color.White,
                        maxLines = 1,
                        fontSize = 12.sp,
                    )

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Here is how I call `CreateList()`

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val view = ComposeView(requireContext())
        view.setContent {
            MaterialTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = Color(34, 39, 46)
                ) {
                    Column {
                        Row {
                            GlideImage(
                                model = args.imageUrl,
                                contentDescription = R.string.dash.toString(),
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .height(200.dp),
                                contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
                            )
                        }
                        CreateTitle(args.name)
                        CreateInfoTextField(getString(R.string.status), args.status)
                        CreateInfoTextField(getString(R.string.species), args.species)
                        CreateInfoTextField(getString(R.string.location), args.location)
                        CreateTitle(getString(R.string.locations))
                    }
                    CreateList(locationItems = viewModel.pagedLocations)
                }
            }

        }

        return view
    }
```

So how do I make my list be at the `bottom and scroll` along with the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.
I just made the LazyColumn the main container

So, my code looks like that:

```
@Composable
fun CreateList(locationItems: Flow<PagingData<LocationsItemsList>>) {

    val lazyLocationItems: LazyPagingItems<LocationsItemsList> =
        locationItems.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    LazyColumn {
        item {
            Row {
                GlideImage(
                    model = args.imageUrl,
                    contentDescription = R.string.dash.toString(),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(200.dp),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
                )
            }
            CreateTitle(args.name)
            CreateInfoTextField(getString(R.string.status), args.status)
            CreateInfoTextField(getString(R.string.species), args.species)
            CreateInfoTextField(getString(R.string.location), args.location)
            CreateTitle(getString(R.string.locations))
        }

        items(lazyLocationItems) {
            it?.let { CreateLocationItem(location = it) }
        }
    }
}
```